# IIS Joomla Ajax error when patching to new version

Tags: ajax, joomla

I am currently running Joomla! 3.6.2 Stable on server 2012 IIS 8. The system is running okay all modules and plugins work as expected. What I cannot do is patch to a later version, I have attempted an update to 3.6.4 and now to 3.6.5 and get the same ajax error. I have opened up the permissions in an attempt to get this upgrade completed but to no avail, is there anybody that can help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Just download Joomla 3.6.5, remove the installation folder (and the templates folder), extract it onto your current Joomla website, and then go to the backend of the Joomla website and go to "Extensions" -> "Manage" -> "Database", and finally click on "Fix".

Make sure you backup your website first (database + filesystem) before doing the manual update.